# Using the basepath filter to re-write URLs in Webby?

Tags: ruby, rake, webby

## Basepath Filter Rewriting?

I'm trying to use the basepath filter in webby to rewrite all of the URLs in my project.

The documentation on the [basepath filter](http://webby.rubyforge.org/user-manual/#h3_6) for [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/) is a little bit "light" concerning this, and there just simply isn't enough of it that I can understand how to use it.

If I find the solution to this, however I plan to **contribute** some documentation to the project.

I also understand that in order for this to work, I'm supposed to have all of my paths for the URLs it rewrites to start with "/".

I've tried applying the filter like so, to my default.txt template...

```
---
extension: html
filter:    erb
       basepath
---
```

** - Top of layouts/default.txt**

Then I run the command:

```
leeand00@someHost: webby rebuild BASE='http://www.yahoo.com/bob/'
```

** - Running the command from the root directory of the project**

but all I get is an error...

```
** Invoke rebuild (first_time)
** Invoke configure_basepath (first_time)
** Execute configure_basepath
** Execute rebuild
webby aborted!
syntax error on line 4, col 0: `---'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:164:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `open'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/layout.rb:19:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:167:in `load_files'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:39:in `find'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:38:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:38:in `find'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:164:in `load_files'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:134:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:23:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/tasks/build.rake:13
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:615:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:615:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2019:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:232:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1991:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:115:in `rake'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:33:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:12:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/bin/webby:39
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/webby:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/webby:19
leeand00@U101:~/J62$ webby --trace rebuild BASE='http://www.yahoo.com/bob/'
** Invoke rebuild (first_time)
** Invoke configure_basepath (first_time)
** Execute configure_basepath
** Execute rebuild
webby aborted!
syntax error on line 4, col 0: `---'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:164:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `open'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/meta_file.rb:51:in `meta_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources/layout.rb:19:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/resources.rb:41:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:167:in `load_files'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:39:in `find'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:38:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/find.rb:38:in `find'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:164:in `load_files'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:134:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/builder.rb:23:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/tasks/build.rake:13
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:615:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:615:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2019:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:232:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1991:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:115:in `rake'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:33:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/lib/webby/apps/main.rb:12:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webby-0.9.3/bin/webby:39
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/webby:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/webby:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your filters section so that it uses valid webby syntax. It should look like this:

```
---
extension: html
filter:
  - erb
  - basepath
---
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've only been using the one filter for so long that I'd forgotten that that was wrong! :)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the answer is correct. I would like to explain why, it is because the meta-data of the pages is in yaml ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Lists )